# "row count" or "rows count" to mean "number of rows"

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am a software developer. In software manuals and source code comments, I see repetitively the phrases "row count" and "rows count" to mean "number of rows".

Are both phrases correct?

Comment: A tooth brush, no matter how many teeth; a potato sack, no matter how many potatoes; a row count; no matter how many rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a software perspective, row count is correct.

As a system variable (see transact sql @@rowcount or set rowcount), the phrase "row count" is commonly understood to mean the count of the rows in the result set. This is convention.

Even outside of software engineering, rows count sounds clunky.  Better English would be 'count of rows', or 'total number of rows' or 'rows returned'.  So I would personally avoid using rows count.